# Checking Available Update data - AJAX error

Tags: ajax, updating

I'm having problems with a local site that I imported to Acquia Dev desktop from one of my live sites.  Everytime I try to Check for Available Update data, I get an Ajax error

> Error Checking Update Data Please Continue to error page An AJAX HTTP
>   request terminated abnormally. Debugging information follows. Path:
>   /batch?id=676&op=do StatusText: ResponseText: ReadyState: 4

Clicking the error page link, drupal returns me to the available updates page with a message

> An error occurred trying to get available update data.

Any ideas?

Thanks
Sharon

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the problem was with Cron, It was not running due to some custom php code.  Remove the code and everything seems fine now.